# Django Authorization- Identify the User in Views

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to develop an app for multiple clients that displays analytics data specific to their account. So far I've set up my views file using the `@login_required` decorator for restricted pages. Now I need to identify that user to obtain their data.

A [bit of research](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/) suggests that I could use:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

session_key = request.session.session_key()

session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
```

Which obviously returns the user_id, which I can use as a field in the analytics database to identify which user the data belongs to.

Is this the best way to go about doing this, or can anyone suggest a better/more elegant alternative?

Note: I haven't tested the solution I've proposed, it just seems workable in my head.

Comment: Here's a walkthrough of adding user authentication so the page displays the username. : http://mdukehall.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/django-python-adventure-part-4/

Comment: Also if you need something more complex/ roles?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546670/django-role-based-views

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the logged in user on the `request` object.

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    user = request.user
    do_something(user)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are in a view, you can access the currently logged in user (object) by

```
def myview(request):
    request.user

    # or, if you want,
    request.user.id
```