# In Django, how do I restrict is_staff member to access a URL?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my web, user and admin user both login from frontend. Now I want to do that some of URLs are accessed by public user only. Is_staff user not access that URL. How do I do that?

Updated:
Can I use any decorator for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that? Your staff users could just log out if they wanted to visit those URLs (so - what do you achieve by not letting them visit when logged in?).

Comment: requirement in my project

Comment: Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546670/django-role-based-views

Comment: *Can we use any decorator for this ?*

Comment: you haven't shown your view code whether you are using class based view or function based view. but yes you can achieve it too using decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inherit `LoginRequiredMixin` and create your own custom access mixin as below:

```
class AccessMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or request.user.is_staff:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now you just need to inherit `AccessMixin` in your view as below:

```
class HomePageView(AccessMixin, TemplateView):
    login_url = <login-url>
    ...
    ...
```

So anonymous user and staff user won't be able to access the content of the page.

---

You can also mention the same in your base template html

Consider you have created a `base.html` which extends `content` block and you can add permission as below:
Ex.
**base.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.is_staff %}
         <h3>Not allowed to access this page</h3>
    {% else %}
         {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

this way when you extend base.html in your template all the content you write within `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` will only be rendered for non-staff logged in user.

Comment: Instead of subclassing `LoginRequiredMixin`, another option would be [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

Comment: @Alasdair agreed!, but I believe you need to write test function too in child class hence need to create custom mixin for it too to avoid writing the same function multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a decorator, you can use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test). First define a test function that checks that the user is not a staff member.

```
def is_not_staff(user):
    return not user.is_staff
```

You can change the function to check `user.is_authenticated` (`user.is_authenticated()` in Django <=1.9) as well, if you don't want anonymous users to be able to access the view.

Then use `user_passes_test` with your test function to decorate the view you wish to protect.

```
@user_passes_test(is_not_staff)
def non_staff_view(request):
    ...
```