# 2 level of users in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am into development of a web based business application using django which will be used by 3 different companies. The business process is exactly same.

I have stucked at user creation.

I need 2 level of users. First the comany detail (higher level)  and second 'n' number of users from that company itself which will be using the application.

I have extended the default user model using ABSTRACTUSER to fulfill my fields requirement but I am not able to configure my requirement.

I am asking for what could be the best way to achieve my goal and I would give a try to it.

I wanted to First signin into company, show related info about company, give options to create new user for that particular company (no option to sign-up for new company here), add and show more related functionalities, etc, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django role based views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546670/django-role-based-views)

Comment: @Mark  I was thinking to first signin into the company, show general inf,  give options to create user for that company, add and show more related functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by multitenany where each tenant has its own admin and users.